# How to test a controller action that does not exist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rails-routing, controller-action

There are only two actions accessible in the `ProductsController`:

```ruby
# /config/routes.rb
RailsApp::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :products, only: [:index, :show]
end
```

Tests are set up accordingly:

```ruby
# /spec/controllers/products_controller_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe ProductsController do

  before do
    @product = Product.gen
  end

  describe "GET index" do
    it "renders the index template" do
      get :index
      expect(response.status).to eq(200)
      expect(response).to render_template(:index)
    end
  end

  describe "GET show" do
    it "renders the show template" do
      get :show, id: @product.id
      expect(response.status).to eq(200)
      expect(response).to render_template(:show)
    end
  end

end
```

How would you test that the other [CRUD actions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions) are **not** accessible? This might change in the future so the tests will ensure any configuration change will be noticed.
I found the [`be_routable` matcher](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/routing-specs/be-routable-matcher) which looks promising to cover the test case.

---

I recommend this [post by Dave Newton which describes when and why to test controller actions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18117630/356895).

Comment: As you've said, routing specs would be enough.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I came up with:

```
context "as any user" do
  describe "not routable actions" do
    it "rejects routing for :new" do
      expect(get: "/products/new").not_to be_routable
    end
    it "rejects routing for :create" do
      expect(post: "/products").not_to be_routable
    end
    it "rejects routing for :edit" do
      expect(get: "/products/#{@product.id}/edit").not_to be_routable
    end
    it "rejects routing for :update" do
      expect(put: "/products/#{@product.id}").not_to be_routable
    end
    it "rejects routing for :destroy" do
      expect(delete: "/products/#{@product.id}").not_to be_routable
    end
  end
end
```

However one test fails:

```
Failure/Error: expect(get: "/products/new").not_to be_routable
  expected {:get=>"/products/new"} not to be routable, 
  but it routes to {:action=>"show", :controller=>"products", :id=>"new"}
```

---

Please feel free to add your own solution if you follow a totally different approach to test non-existing routes.

Comment: If you add a constaint on id in your routes it will work: constraints(id: /\d+/)